# Conflicting definitions of Quadratic form in Hoffman Kunze linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

This question is about the exact definition of a quadratic form.

On page 273, the authors defined:

> ... **quadratic form** determined by the inner product is the function that assigns to each $\alpha$ the scalar $\|\alpha\|^2$...

On page 368, the authors defined:

> Definition. Let $f$ be a bilinear form on the vector space V. We say that $f$ is symmetric $f(\alpha, \beta) = f(\beta, \alpha)$  for all $\alpha, \beta$ in $V$.

> If $f$ is a symmetric bilinear form, the **quadratic form** associated with $f$ is the function $q$ from $V$ into $F$ defined by $q(\alpha)= f(\alpha, \alpha)$.

But complex Inner product is obviously not a bilinear form. Is there a typo or they are just two distinct concepts happening to use the same terminology?

Here is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158912/549321).

Comment: Neither of these appear to be a definition of quadratic form. Rather, they are talking about quadratic forms. Unless “inner product” is a more expansive term than usual.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, so you mean a good definition of quadratic form is like from wiki: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Quadratic_form. And both of my examples happen to satisfy this definition?

Comment: Can you provide the books’ definition of bilinear form? That might be the error.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these sentences define a quadratic form. Here is a definition: if $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$, a [**quadratic form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Definitions) on $V$ is a function $q : V \to K$ such that $q(av) = a^2 q(v)$ for $a \in K$ and such that the function $q(u + v) - q(u) - q(v)$ is bilinear.

If $B : V \times V \to K$ is a symmetric bilinear form, you can check that $q(v) = B(v, v)$ is a quadratic form satisfying $q(u + v) - q(u) - q(v) = 2 B(u, v)$. If the characteristic of $K$ is not equal to $2$ then this gives a natural bijection between quadratic forms and symmetric bilinear forms.

Now let $V$ be a complex inner product space. The function $\| v \|^2 = \langle v, v \rangle$ is *not* a quadratic form over $\mathbb{C}$, because $ \| a v \|^2 = |a|^2 \| v \|^2$. This corresponds, as you say, to the complex inner product not being bilinear. However, it *is* a quadratic form over $\mathbb{R}$. In fact if $V = \mathbb{C}^n$ with the usual inner product it is a slightly disguised form of the usual Euclidean quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. So the term "quadratic form" is still warranted here but one has to be a bit careful as you say.

Comment: One might add that, even in more abstract situations with a quadratic Galois extension $K$ of base field $k$, the notion of _hermitian_ form generalizes the case of $\mathbb C/\mathbb R$: with $\sigma$ the non-trivial Galois element, $\langle y,x\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle^\sigma$ replaces literal symmetry, etc.